# Laravel 8 + LiveWire + Datepicker

Tags: laravel, livewire

Прошу помощи и совета.
Смысл такой - есть таблица в БД, есть вьюха, в которой эта таблица выводится через LiveWire. Есть опять же фильтр по значению поля (опять же на LiveWire) Хочу сделать фильтрацию не только по значению поля, но и еще по датам - типа диапазон дат из которого выводятся все значения. Для выбора дат использую кастомный DatePicker (air-datapicker). Но засада в том, что при обновлении поля с датой, вывод таблицы не фильтруется, хотя я вижу, что запрос уходит...

**BLADE:**

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <label>Фильрация: </label><br>
        <li>
            <label>Поиск Выданного Токена: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="text" wire:model="ID" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Начальная Дата: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type='text' wire:model="startDate" class='datepicker-here' data-position="bottom left" data-autoClose="false" data-date-Format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-auto-close="true" onfocus="this.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'))"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label>Конечная Дата: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <input type='text' wire:model="endDate" class='datepicker-here' data-position="bottom left" data-autoClose="false" data-date-Format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-auto-close="true" onfocus="this.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'))" />


        </li>
    </div>
```

**LiveWire:**

```
class Search extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $ID;
    public $startDate;


    public function render()
    {
        $ID = '%'.$this->ID.'%';
        $startDate = '%'.$this->startDate.'%';
        return view('livewire.oauthtokens.search', [
            
            'Tokens' => DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)->paginate(10)
            
        ]);
        
    }
}
```